# jQuery ajax not working remotely on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, parse-error

I have some code on the client that calls an ashx handler using $.ajax() and expects json data from the server. Everything works fine on FF, IE 6,7,8 when I run the application on a local webserver. However, when I deploy the application to a remote test server, IEs stopped working ($.ajax returns a parsererror), while FF continues to work as expected.

My first thought was that my json object must have a trialing comma which IEs hate, but that wasn't the issue as there were no trialing commas. Then, I tried changing various things like the content types from app/json to tex/plain, still the same error.

Something that I found odd is that if I fire up fiddler, then IEs will work remotely, otherwise, I get the parsererror.

Has anyone experienced something like this before? Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "handlers/GetAsyncResults.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {'from': dateFrom, 'to': dateTo, 'accountId' : aId, 'page': currentPage, 'sortField' : sortField, 'sortDirection' : sortDirection},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { GetAsyncResultsEnd(data); },
        error: function(x, y, z) { GetAsyncResultsErrorHandler(x, y, z); }
    });
```

EDIT: added code snippet.

Comment: Can you drop in a snippet of the client code?

Comment: Try appending ?r=9028374 (some random string) just to confirm it's not caching.

Comment: Is the ashx handler on the same server as the document that calls it?

Comment: It's defintiley not caching. And everything lives on the same server/domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's sorted. Thanks.

On the server end, after we called context.Response.Write(*'Our json data'*), we then call context.Response.Flush() and context.Response.Close(). After we removed the .Flush() and .Close(), everything started working again. But I still can't explain why it's working for firefox and not IE, nor how fiddler magically made it works for IE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that has given me a parse error before it invalid JSON.  You said that you checked for trailing spaces, but try running your json through - [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).  That has worked well for me.  It is interesting though that fiddler helps.

Comment: Just tried Json Lint, my jsons are valid according to the site. Thanks.

Comment: Two things - can you post an example of your JSON response?  And I haven't used JQuery's json type.  I always took the text and ran it through Crockfords JSON.parse.  It would be interesting to see if the issue persists when using that method - but maybe JQuery is using his JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply removing the datatype: "json"

I had this same problem and removing that fixed it. Removing that allows jQuery to "intelligently pass either responseXML or responseText to your success callback".

Answer (score 0):

In my ashx.cs method, I had to comment out the Flush() in order for this to work.

Prior to this, my json was well-formed, and everything appeared to work, but the JavaScript (JQuery .ajax POST call) would just return nothing, FireBug would not report an error, the console was not reporting an error, nothing.  It all worked locally (in Visual Studio), but not when everything was on the server.

```
//code from the ashx.cs file...
//...after populating the response, resp:

JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(resp);

r.Write(json);
//r.Flush();  /////commented out!  It returns to the .js file correctly!
....
```