# jQuery.ajax event not firing properly in IE8 (except when Fiddler is loaded)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, internet-explorer-8

This is possibly the weirdest error I've ever encountered:

So I have a bundle of jQuery.ajax calls to a web service I threw together. It works great in Firefox and Chrome, but it does nothing in IE8 *unless* I have Fiddler running. (It's similar to the issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297673/jquery-ajax-not-working-remotely-on-ie), but I've tried the stuff mentioned to no avail.)

In these non-functional calls, it seems like it's building the jqXHR object like it should, but something is missing. Not sure what, though - I'm not super-intimate with the inner workings of jQuery, so stepping through the call in the debugger can only do so much for me.

Here's the call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 30000,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});

$.ajax({
url: "/PSWS/UserManager.asmx/Login",
data: '{"emailAddress":"' + myEmailAddress + '","password":"' + myPassword + '","stayLoggedIn":' + (myStayLoggedIn ? 'true' : 'false') + '}',
success: function (response) {
    if (!response.Success) {
        alert(response.Message);
    } else {
        $(this).find('.message').remove();
        $.fn.colorbox.close();
    }
},
dataType: 'json',
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $(this).find('.message').remove();
    $(this).prepend('<div class="message message_error">Error!<br/>' + jqXHR.status + ' - ' + jqXHR.statusText + '</div>');
}
```

});`

I wondered if something was wrong in my JSON, either in what's sent or what's received. I don't know of a way to capture this except through Fiddler, but it seems to be valid. Valid enough for its parser and JSONLint, anyway.

Sent:
`{"emailAddress":"test@example.com","password":"asdasdasd","stayLoggedIn":true}`

Received:
`{"__type":"PSUserManagerService.SystemResponse","Success":false,"Message":"Error logging in: Invalid username and/or password.","Subscriptions":null}`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem.

In my case this was caused by NTLM (SSO) authentification.

Internet Explorer checks the **NTLM authetication on each post-Request**:

---

Request Header (from DebugBar Plugin)

*Cookie: JSESSIONID=2323......323239*

*Authorization: NTLM....*

---

I don't know why it does work with fiddler...maybe through this proxy the authentification headers are manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Witali is probably right that this could be related to NTLM authentication.

In my case, it's very hard to diagonize the problem. I have 3 networks: dev, testing and prod with similar configurations. The same IE 8 can successfully POST JSON object to dev and testing but not prod. So it shouldn't be the client side problem. Then I also exclude server's problem such as application or versioning, because Chrom and Firefox can succeed in posting to the same prod server's app. However, it does look more like a client problem because if I use fiddler, then it would work in prod.

Anyway, the final solution I experimented was to Enable Windows Authentication at site level rarther than just application level in IIS (my site has several applications underneath).

You would also have to IIS (site) -> Windows Authentication->Advanced Settings->Providers, make NTLM top rather than Negociate.

Hope this helps.